# multi-spectral high resolution satellite images for forests Greece (for vegetation indices)

Tags: images

Looking for open-source high-resolution multi-spectral images (raster data) for Greece in order to analyze the vegetation indices of small forests smaller than 1kmx1km. Preferably if the data is from multiple years in order to see a progression in the forests.